# Image style drupal

Tags: drupal

Please let me know below code is correct to fetch the image style in drupal

```
$image = theme(
  'image_style',
  array(
    'path' => 'public://my_example_image.jpg',
    'style_name' => 'my_custom_image_style',
    'alt' => 'Alternate Text',
    'title' => 'Title Text',
  )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch image url in specific style with:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7

One parameter is image style name and other is image URI (not the path!). You can manually define image tag content and for href attribute print out value image_style_url() returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
 $img_url = $node->field_image['und'][0]['uri'];
 <img src="<?php print image_style_url("thumbnail", $img_url); ?>" />
```

You can change 'thumbnail' to your image style name,and replace $img_url with your image field machine name.